# how to insert jpeg image into excel sheet in unix

Tags: python, excel, unix, xlwt

I am able to insert bmp images using `insert_bitmap` command of the `xlwt` module in python using the following code:

```
import xlwt    
from PIL import Image   
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet3 = book.add_sheet('diagrams') 
Image.open('violations.png').convert("RGB").save('violations.bmp')    
sheet3.insert_bitmap('violations.bmp',5,13)
book.save('simple.xls')
```

This is correctly inserting the bmp image into the sheet but my concern is that the bmp image is around 3MB and I am unable to compress it without significant quality loss.

Is there some way to insert jpeg images into a worksheet in unix ?

Comment: Have you tried passing a .jpg image to `insert_bitmap()`? It might work because "bitmap" is a generic term for image files in general and doesn't just apply those stored in .bmp format files.

Comment: I have tried passing .jpg image and it is not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From looking at the code it looks like xlwt only supports 24bit bitmap images.

The [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) Python module can insert PNG images (or JPEG or Bitmap). Here is an example:

```
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = Workbook('images.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Widen the first column to make the text clearer.
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 30)

# Insert an image.
worksheet.write('A2', 'Insert an image in a cell:')
worksheet.insert_image('B2', 'python.png')

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image: XlsxWriter Image example]

See the [relevant section of the docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html#insert_image) for further information.

Comment: xlsxwriter looks great, but unfortunately it is not installed in my unix system and i am not allowed to install anything. so still looking for any other options

Comment: @sidharthcnadhan: Since the package is pure Python (no binaries, no C extensions to compile, etc.) it technically doesn't need to be "installed".  It can just live in the same directory as the program you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

from 
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_images.html

if you need to offset -and- scale an image in one insert:

> > worksheet.insert_image('B5', 'python.png', {'x_offset': 2, 'y_offset': 2, 'x_scale': 0.5, 'y_scale': 0.5})

this took me a second to figure out, thought it might save others some time